# Calculate the eigenvalues of the symmetric part of $A$ form the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^T$ without calculating the symmetric part of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We have the matrix $A$, 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}
$$
Clearly $A$ is orthogonal and has eigenvalues $1, e^{2i\pi/3}, e^{-2i\pi/3}$, which are the same for $A^T$. I have a question which wants the eigenvalues of the symmetric part of $A$ from the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^T$ without explicitly calculating the symmetric part of $A$. It seems like it should be simple, but I'm struggling to get this.

Since $Tr A = \sum_{i=0}^3 \lambda_i$ the sum of the eigenvalues of the symmetric part is $0$, but I'm not sure where else to go. Any hints?

Comment: Would they be the real parts of the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: What is a symmetric part of $A$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks, that makes sense, I guess it only applies to orthogonal matrices? I've had a think, but how would you start showing that the real parts of A are the eigenvalues of $1/2(A+A^T)$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, this would only hold true, if the symmetric and skew-symmetric parts of $A$ have the same basis of eigenvectors. This is not necessarly the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A+A^T=A+A^{-1}$ has the eigenvalues $\lambda+\frac{1}{\lambda}$. Since $|\lambda|=1$ it is the same as $\lambda+\bar\lambda=2 \mathrm{Re}\,\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks, why can I state that the eigenvalues of $A+A^T$ are the sum of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^T$?

Comment: Yep I see this, so  $(A+A^T)x=\mu x$ so $\lambda x + 1/\lambda x = \mu x$

Comment: @Ambler It is because $A+A^T=A+A^{-1}$ and the latter is a function of the same matrix. It is easy to see that $A$ and $A^{-1}$ share the eigenvectors (for a general matrix $A$).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint (?):** Notice that every eigenvector of $A$ is also an eigenvector of $A^T$.